# curl LinkedIn API

Tags: api, curl, linkedin-api

I obtained the oauth token and oauth token secret for the LinkedIn API via Python. I'd like to make some REST calls via curl now and I tried the following ;

```
curl -v "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~" -d "oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxx" -d "oauth_token_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

I've used the LinkedIn API in Python but wanted to use in curl. Am I missing something here ?
Any suggestions in this regard will be highly appreciated.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to sign the requests using OAuth - usually the best way to do this is to use a library (like you mentioned, the python library works well).  You can scoop the HTTP traffic to see what additional headers are being sent.  The developer portal at http://developer.linkedin.com has an overview of the OAuth stuff, but it'd be pretty tough to get a working implementation for Curl because each signature you generate will be different (based on timestamp).

Comment: @Kirsten,
So you mean If I want to use cURL, wget or any commandline utility to use linkedIn API; I would not be able to do it.
Even If i have generated valid API key, secret key, OAuth user token & OAuth secret key?